# difference between availability and accessiblity in inheritance

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have a small doubt regarding this MCQ question on inheritance. I hope someone can help me with it.

[image: mcq]

The correct answer is c and i get it but my doubt is:

The **option b** states *Private members of parent class are  available in child class*

and in inhertance *Private members of parent class are not **accessible** in child class*

so is **availability and accessiblity** different things in this context?? cause if its available in child class as private members then why can't i access them in the child class itself?

So can this also be the answer? only single option was clickable and no 4th option like both b and c were given.

Comment: I can't find a formal definition of what *availability* means in the context of C++ class inheritance. But consider this: What if the child class is a `friend` of its parent?

Comment: What a terribly phrased question.

Comment: If I saw a quiz question that had a full stop (period) in the middle of a sentence, I would question the validity of the whole website.

Comment: The correct answer to (c) is 'it depends'.

Comment: The correct answer to (b) depends on the meaning of available, which has no commonly accepted definition as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Only (a) seems to have a reasonable answer.

Comment: The phrasing of the question is a joke.

Comment: This MCQ question is horribly vague. Don't waste any time on figuring out what it's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Availability concerns name lookup. A derived class can find it's base class' private members even if it can't do anything with them.

Consider the following case of multiple inheritance. `derived` inherits from two base classes which each has a `int x;` member, one `private` and the other `public` (https://godbolt.org/z/fPKjKczzb) :

```
class base1
{
private:
    int x;
};

class base2
{
public:
    int x;
};

class derived : public base1, public base2
{
    void func()
    {
        // error: reference to 'x' is ambiguous
        x = 1;
    }
};
```

Here `derived` has 2 `x;` members available even if it can only access one. Therefore `x = 1;` is actually ambiguous. It seems intuitive that `x = 1;` should refer to `base2::x` but that isn't how name lookup rules are defined.

In my opinion, the linked question is poorly written. Even if you know the difference between availability and accessibility, which is rather obscure, it's easy to fall for the tricky wording. It seems designed to trick as many people as possible and doesn't seem to be of any value in evaluating actual knowledge or competence.

Comment: This worries me a little. Suppose I've written class base1 as part of a published library. I thought I could make a change by adding a private member without breaking existing usages in client source code. But as you've shown, this is not the case. So the Cheshire Cat idiom is useful for source-code compatibility too, not just for binary compatibility.

Comment: @k314159 Don't *ever* expect binary compatibility for C++ code. Except if it was all compiled at the same time with the *exact same* compiler using the *exact same* compiler options. Expect C++ to be a language that is *source* compatible, *not* binary compatible - or you *will* get burned eventually.

Comment: I assume this is the intended meaning of "available", but that's certainly not in the Standard and isn't used widely enough that a test should assume a meaning is or should be understood.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That seems a little extreme. The Itanium ABI makes it possible to make C++ libraries usable with different compiler versions, some cases of different compiler flags, and even mixing g++ and clang++. Yes, there are more things that can go wrong than with C, so care is required. But it's not a hopeless task.